# Vertical middle content in div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I using bootstrap. Does bootstrap have selector put text in the middle in the div rather than at the top?

See example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/23497/

Can you can see `Create user accounts for your staff` is at the top which should be in the middle lined up with a button.

How to do this in bootstrap?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Create user accounts for your staff.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " href="#">Add Staff</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bootstrap lacks native support for what you are trying to accomplish.  Using `flexbox` for your Grid might work depending on the browser support you need to offer.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @RobertC I have tried `vertical-align: middle` and no luck.

Comment: That is because `col-md-8` and `col-md-4` do not share the same `height`. That's where `flexbox` has an advantage; you can configure it to apply equal heights.

Comment: Oh. I might as well set `col-md-8` to fixed height maybe `height:60px` with `vertical-align: middle` that might fix it?

Comment: It would take a bit more than that; `vertical-align` works best when you also use `display:table` and at that point you're breaking your `col-*-*` functionality unless you apply it to a new class: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back I posted an answer that solve this, but it seems a simple vertical-align and maybe you need something else and the question is not very clear. In this case, can you add more details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the capability of using `flex` you can extend Bootstrap to support a vertical `flexbox` solution using just a bit of simple CSS:

```css
.row.row-vertical {
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-vertical">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Create user accounts for your staff.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " href="#">Add Staff</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: You can read more about FlexBox and its support here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row .col-md-4,
.row .col-md-8{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row row-vertical">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        Create user accounts for your staff.
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="clearfix">
            <div class="pull-right">
                <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary " href="#">Add Staff</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated the answer with the snippet. I first thought is ok without because the css have few lines, but I saw the other example and I wanted to add here also. Thank you @RobertC.

Answer (score -2):

add these rules to your css

```
.col-md-8,.col-md-4{
  display:inline-block !important;
  vertical-align:middle !important;
  }
  .col-md-4{
    float:right !important
  }
```

It is wise to add an Id to your specific html elements to prevent breaking bootstrap and add these css rules to your ids.good luck...

Comment: This answer would fundamentally break Bootstrap Grid for any purpose outside this instance.  I would recommend providing a more future-proof solution that relies on additional classes, rather than overriding framework functionality and placing `!important` on all the things.

Comment: why the downvote add these to a jsfiddle at the buttom of the fiddle provided and see the results....

Comment: @ Robert C..Have you seen in my answer I use a !important "on all all things" as you said...?

Comment: @repzerro - Your solution creates additional problems.  The user would no longer be able to use `.col-md-8` or `.col-md-4` under the default Bootstrap functionality.  `.col-md-4` would always have a `float:right` regardless of whether it was needed, etc.  Your solution works, but it's heavy-handed and there are better approaches.

Comment: Maybe the user can add an id to the html tags and use the css rules I provided..I am not going to give a big solution of codes to fix his whole bootstrap...Stackoverflow will provide an approach..would be care to post answer of your thorough solution Mr. Robert C?